# Why can I have two entites in the same persistence context with the same id

Tags: jpa

```
public void whyEntityExistsExceptionisnotthrown(){
    EntityManager em=getEntityManager();
    try{
        Partner partnerOne=em.find(Partner.class, 1L); // from the database
        System.out.println("Partner partnerOne  information-----------> "+partnerOne.getName());
        Partner partnerTwo =new Partner();
        partnerTwo.setIdpartner(1L);
        partnerTwo.setName("Partner 200");
        em.persist(partnerTwo);         
        Partner partnerThree=em.find(Partner.class, 1L);
        // the method find has two entities with the id 1L. I think this could be a problem.            
        if(em.contains(partnerOne))
                System.out.println("PartnerOne managed");
        if(em.contains(partnerTwo))
            System.out.println("PartnerTwo managed");

        System.out.println("Partner partnerTwo  information-----------> "+partnerTwo.getName());
        System.out.println("Partner partnerThree  information-----------> "+partnerThree.getName());

    }catch(EntityExistsException e){
            System.out.println("The entity already exist");
    }
}
```

Through this post I try to see that problems can arise by allowing two entities have the same id in a persistence context. 
The question is:
Is there a way to avoid that there may be two managed entities with the same id in a persistence context before calling the flush method or commit?
Why not throw the exception persist?

If I call this method the result is:

First call to whyEntityExistsExceptionisnotthrown
partnerOne: the information from the database (I've got a partner in database with id=1)
partnerTwo:   Name=Partner 200
partnerThree: Name=Partner 200 (but could have been the information of partnerOne.

Next Call
        partnerOne ------> Name=Partner 200
    partnerTwo ------> Name=Partner 200
        partnerThree ----> Name=Partner 200

Comment: ??? who is `socio1` and `uno` ?

Comment: I'm guessing that `em.persist(partner1)` has overwritten (in the database) the data that you think is in `socio1`.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in the code. partner1 is  a new Entity persisted, therefore managed, and partnerone is an entity catched from the database by a entitymanager.find method and therefore managed too. Why is this possible. I only get exception if i try to commit changes to the database.

Comment: Please check the code again, and tell me if the behavior is right.

Comment: I don't understand your question: the title asks one, and in your question you ask something else.... Is there an Entity in your DB when you call `em.persist(partner1);` ?

Comment: Also could you show us your entity class (I need the mapping if the ID field)?

Comment: I'll change the code to try to show the situations that I think could be problematic because of this behavior.

Comment: Check with your provider if there is a way to throw the exception up front.  If a managed entity with that id is already in the persistence unit, some providers will throw the exception upfront - it doesn't require a database hit to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of the [persist()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist%28java.lang.Object%29) method, it throws an

> EntityExistsException - if the entity already exists. (If the entity
>   already exists, the EntityExistsException may be thrown when the
>   persist operation is invoked, or the EntityExistsException **or another
>   PersistenceException may be thrown at flush or commit time**.)

So to be sure that your `persist()` reaches the DB, you should call `em.flush()` right after persisting the entity and you will get **one** exception (either EntityExistsException on calling `persist` or EntityExistsException/PersistenceException `flush`). Yes, one could ask himself why the JPA specification is not very clear in this point, but I am pretty sure there is good reason for that, like performance (trying to make a single I/O operation to DB). So, if you want portable/working code, call the `flush()` operation. You probably do not understand that most operations like `remove`, `merge`, `persist` are not guaranteed to reach to DB until the transaction commit. So it is your duty to call `flush()` when needed.

**So to answer your questions:**

> Is there a way to avoid that there may be two managed entities with
>   the same id in a persistence context before calling the flush method
>   or commit?

I doubt that, and also I haven't found so far the need for that (!call flush!). Also as far as I know, the JPA spec. does not require that.

> Why not throw the exception persist?

Because the `persist` is not guaranteed to be synchronized to DB in that moment. The documentation says that pretty clear.

**Some important notes:**
As I understand from your code, your ID field is NOT autogenerated. Usually the applications lets the DB to generate the ID, so that calling `persist` gets synchronized to DB.

Also, in your code (without testing it) I am sure that `partnerOne==partnerThree` is evaluated as true, meaning they are actually EXACTLY THE SAME object. The only problem is with the `partnerTwo`, which you must flush.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, you're right, if I call flush I get the exception. But I would find out before calling flush. Imagine this situation:          Partner partnerOne=em.find(Partner.class, 1L); // from the database
   System.out.println("Partner partnerOne  information-----------> "+partnerOne.getName());
        Partner partnerTwo =new Partner();
   partnerTwo.setIdpartner(1L);
        partnerTwo.setName("Partner 200");
   em.persist(partnerTwo);   
   Partner partnerThree=em.find(Partner.class, 1L); The find method has two entities with the same id and I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Look at the new code to understand what I'm trying to avoid.After em.persist(partnerTwo) call, I think the exception should be thrown, because a subsequent call to the find method: Partner partnerThree=em.find(Partner.class, 1L) could be a problem due we have two entities in the persistence contex with the same id.

Comment: Please see my updated answer (*with **Some important notes***). I hope it makes it clear.